# reconstructing a file path in java

Tags: java, file, properties, filepath

I have a file path location as such:

```
Properties readProp = \\192.168.41.84\dev\config\dev\config.properties
```

how can I manipulate it so I remove the portion of config.properties
and replace it with test\config.properties

so the new Properties location would be:

```
Properties readProp = \\192.168.41.84\dev\config\dev\test\newconfig.properties
```

?

thanks for your time and effort

Comment: Can you create [`SSCCE`](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you escape any backslashes you have as you build the string.

```
String path = "\\\\192.168.41.84\\dev\\config\\dev\\config.properties";
System.out.println(path);
int lastBackSlash = path.lastIndexOf("\\");
//+1 to include lastBackSlash
String newPath = path.substring(0, lastBackSlash + 1) + "test" + path.substring(lastBackSlash);
System.out.println(newPath);
```

Prints

```
\\192.168.41.84\dev\config\dev\config.properties
\\192.168.41.84\dev\config\dev\test\config.properties
```

This article like this is also decent read. Treating paths as strings can be dangerous.

http://twistedoakstudios.com/blog/Post4872_dont-treat-paths-like-strings

However, if your careful, know what how your string functions behave(or look them up), and you don't have off by 1 errors... then treating the paths like strings should be pain free. But you will have no guarantee that the path is valid... while a path builder library would give you that assurance.